# Discord.py 'NoneType' has no attribute 'delete' when trying to delete a thread

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord.py command which deletes threads with a given ID by using [get_thread](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=threads#discord.Guild.get_thread).
I tried to get the thread with `ctx.channel.get_thread(id)`. I am not sure wether it is a coroutine or not, so I don't really know if it should be awaited or not, but in both cases, I got an exception.

I want the user to put in the ID of the thread after the command as a parameter instead of copy and pasting the IDs in my code, like `/delete_thread 123456789`.

Here is the code:

```py
@bot.hybrid_command(name="delete_thread", description="Deletes a thread")
async def delete_thread(ctx, *, id):
    thread = ctx.channel.get_thread(id)
    await thread.delete()
```

I'm expecting the `delete()` function to work like with a normal channel.

I think the ID may be the problem because I can't pass the `id` parameter as an int, like `async def delete_thread(ctx, *, id: int)`.

Comment: Are you passing the integer `123456789`, or are you passing the string `"123456789"`? (And even if you *are* passing an `int`, are you sure the head exists to *be* deleted? You need to check the return value of `get_thread`, not just assume it worked as expected.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `id` is a string but IDs are integer not strings. You need to convert it into an `int` either with `int(id)` or with type hints, which I would prefer:

```py
@bot.hybrid_command(name="delete_thread", description="Deletes a thread")
async def delete_thread(ctx, thread_id: int):
    thread = ctx.channel.get_thread(thread_id)
    await thread.delete()
```

Also, from the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.get_thread):

> This does not always retrieve archived threads, as they are not retained in the internal cache. Use `Guild.fetch_channel()` instead.

In other words: If the thread is archived, use [`fetch_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_channel) instead. In this case I would first check if the thread can be retrieved with `get_` to prevent making an unnessecary API call with `fetch_`:

```py
thread = ctx.channel.get_thread(thread_id)
if thread is None:
    thread = await ctx.guild.fetch_channel(thread_id)

await thread.delete()
```

**Other things to mention:**

- Don't use `id` as your parameter name, because it's a built-in function
- You don't have to use the asterisk `*`, because the ID is one word and not multiple
- `get_thread` is not a coroutine, refer to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.get_thread)

Comment: I had to enter the ID as a string and then convert it to an ```int```, but now it works with both slash commands and prefix commands.

Answer (score 0):

First, `get_thread` is not a coroutine method which means you don't need to `await` it. 
Second, you need to check the thread and then delete if exists. Because if the thread with given ID does not exist, `thread` will be None and you will get that error. Something like

```py
thread = ctx.channel.get_thread(id)
if thread:
  await thread.delete()
else:
  await ctx.send("Thread does not exist")
```